# iOS exposure algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, camera

I need implement camera exposure change for video recording. I look for default autoexposure:

```
_device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
```

It works fine. But I need more complicated logic with exposure and wide range of Exposure time change [0.01, 0.8]. Default algorithm have [0.01, 0.25] of Exposure time range. So I try to repeat apple algorithm. I know when image might be lighter or darker, but I need implement some logic for ISO and Exposure time change. I already implement my algorithm but it works not how I need.

Some result of experiments with standard algorithm (I capture standard exposure change when environment light change; exposure scaled for normal display on chart):
[image]

Comment: You want to learn about "The Exposure Triangle." (see http://digital-photography-school.com/learning-exposure-in-digital-photography/). It isn't clear from your question what your problem is, why is your algorithm bad? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: From light image to dark I start change ISO, ofter some threshold I change ISO and Exposure time simultaneously. After ISO get limit, i continious change Exposure time until limit. Also exposure time have not linear behavior. I use formula from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value to get linearity. It works not so well. Default algorithm works much better. In your link there dependencies of this values. Maybe you have resource for mathematical exploration all values, how it depend on image brightness.

Comment: Sadly, I'm a photographer, not a imaging scientist. What you are trying to do is hard, I know that. The algorithm you use will affect the image results.

Comment: Are you still interested in this? Also which device is the ISO graph derived from?